# SQL IF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a query and part of the query must return values based on when the transaction occurred.

A simpler version of the table would be as follows

```
TransDate | TransAmt    
--------------------
6/1/2012  | 10
7/5/2012  | 15
6/1/2013  | 15
7/1/2013  | 15
```

The restriction is that any Transactions that occurred before(TransDate) 6/30/2012 would return the full TransAmt.  If the transaction happened after 6/30/2012, the value for TransAmt must be returned as 0.

I believe I would need to use the CAST function as well as the CASE function but I am not experienced with either functions.  Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2008 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when TransDate < '2012-06-30' then TransAmt else 0 end)
. . .
```

I would strongly encourage you to use ISO standard date formats (YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `case`:

```
select case when TransDate < '6/30/2012' then TransAmt else 0 end
from tbl
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e49432/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the CASE statement would look like:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN TransDate <= '2012-06-30' THEN TransAmt
          WHEN TransDate > '2012-06-30' THEN 0
        END)
 FROM Table_1
```

You may want to remove the = depending on whether or not you want 2012-06-30 to be included or not.